# PyQT freezing upon running pynput function

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

Im trying to run a pynput function after clicking a button, the returned value is then set as text in the main GUI.

the function is working but in case pynput module is not exited quickly the GUI freeze.

the main GUI code:

```
def getstartloc(self):
        mouse_get = getmouseloc.getpos()
        pos = mouse_get.run()
        self.mouse_start_x.setText(str(pos[0]))
        self.mouse_start_y.setText(str(pos[1]))
```

the pynput module:

```
class getpos():

       def run(self):
            self.start()
            return self.pos

        def on_press(self, key):
            try:
                a = str(key.char)
            except AttributeError:
                a = str(key)
            if a == "m":self.m_pressed = True
            if a != "m":self.m_pressed = False<

            try:
                if  self.m_pressed == True:
                    self.pos = pyautogui.position()
                    return False
            except:pass


        def start(self):
            with KeyboardListener(on_press=self.on_press) as listener:
                    listener.join()
```

i think that the issue is related to the PyQT thread and could be solved by threading but im new to python and programming overall , so im not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

You launch a blocking thread so you block the scheduler of Qt until you have the return of your thread. I suggest you use a "keyPressEvent" or QThead using the signal/slot mechanism to return your event to your main thread. You should also use the built-in qt tools for keyboard and mouse events.

Example implementation:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("mousePressEvent at pos", QCursor.pos())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):


        pos = QCursor.pos()

        print("keyPressEvent key=%i at pos=[%i,%i]"%(event.key(), pos.x(), pos.y()))

        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter:
            # Update label here
            print("Key enter pressed at pos ",QCursor.pos())
        # elif ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Qt keys type:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum

Or with qt thread:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal

class MyGetPosThread(QThread):

    positionSign  = Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def addPositionEventListener(self, listener):
        self.positionSign.connect(listener)

    def on_press(self, key):
        try:
            a = str(key.char)
        except AttributeError:
            a = str(key)
        if a == "m":self.m_pressed = True
        if a != "m":self.m_pressed = False<

        try:
            if  self.m_pressed == True:
                self.positionSign.emit(pyautogui.position())
                return False
        except:pass

    def run(self):
        # It is not a very good approach to start a thread in the qt thread.
        # I suggest looking for keyboard / mouse events in a loop
        # and emit the position when the desired key is pressed
        with KeyboardListener(on_press=self.on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self._get_pos_thread = MyGetPosThread(self)
        self._get_pos_thread.addPositionEventListener(self.onPosEvent)
        self._get_pos_thread.start()

    def onPosEvent(self, pos):
        print(pos)
        # Update lebel here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Note: this only catches events inside of the application.